# create a 2D array of html video objects in p5.js - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a 2D array of video objects. The code works for a regular array however when turning it into a 2D I get the error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tv' of undefined. I think the issue is in this line of code: tvObjArray.push(new NewTvObj(createVideo(videoFiles[i][j]), false, 0, 0));

Code:

```
var tvObjArray = [[],[]];
var videoFiles = [
  ["videos/cityDream.mp4", "videos/cityDream.mp4"],
  ["videos/cityDream.mp4", "videos/cityDream.mp4"]
];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 576);
  // create a new tv object for each screen that needs to appear
  for (var i = 0; i < videoFiles.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < videoFiles[i].length; j++) {
      tvObjArray.push(
        new NewTvObj(createVideo(videoFiles[i][j]), false, 0, 0));
      tvObjArray[i][j].tv.loop();
      tvObjArray[i][j].tv.hide();
      tvObjArray[i][j].tv.pause();
    }
  }
}

function NewTvObj(tvObj, playingBool, xposVal, yposVal) {
  this.tv = tvObj;
  this.playing = playingBool;
  this.xpos = xposVal;
  this.ypos = yposVal;
}

function draw() {
  // locate tvs on building
  for (var i = 0; i < videoFiles.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < videoFiles[i].length; j++) {
  image(tvObjArray[i][j].tv, tvObjArray[i][j].xpos + i * 320, 
    tvObjArray[i][j].ypos + j * 200);
}

drawSprites();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this :

```
  var NewTvObj = function(tvObj, playingBool, xposVal, yposVal) {
  this.tv = tvObj;
  this.playing = playingBool;
  this.xpos = xposVal;
  this.ypos = yposVal;
}
```

and make sure you define the tvObjArray.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared "tvObjArray." Since you're accessing that in a number of places, you need to declare in the root:

```
var tvObjArray = [];
```

Your "tvObjArray" doesn't have the nesting that you "videoFiles" has.  When you push your video into "tvObjArray", that's just a single object that's in the "tvObjArray" and it has no intrinsic link to "i" nor "j".  I'd do something like this instead:

```
var tvObj1 = new NewTvObj(createVideo(videoFiles[i][j]), false, 0, 0);
tvObj1.tv.loop();
tvObj1.tv.hide();
tvObj1.tv.pause();
tvObjArray.push( tvObj );
```

This new object is now at tvObjArray[tvObjArray.length-1];

Also, a handy shortcut for your for loops is this:

```
for (var i in videoFiles) {
  for (var j in videoFiles[i]) {
```

I'm not familiar with p5, so that's as far as I can help.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you! This ended up working   `tvObjArray[i][j] = new NewTvObj(createVideo(videoFiles[i][j]), false, 100, 100);`